# Is the Series Convergent or Divergent?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

> Is
>   $$\sum^\infty_{n=4}\frac{3^{2n}}{(-10)^n}$$
>   Convergent or Divergent? Explain why.

I know I can do:
$$\sum^\infty_{n=4}\frac{9^{n}}{(-10)^n} \Rightarrow \sum^\infty_{n=4}\bigg(\frac{9}{-10}\bigg)^n$$
But I'm not sure where to go from here. The negative denominator is really throwing me off.

Comment: Can you show it is absolutely convergent?

Comment: If not, the alternating series test will work.

Comment: I have not learned the alternating series test yet, that is the next section. I'm assuming I can't use that.

Comment: @MattS Sorry I just saw your comment now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a geometric series, with ratio $-\frac{9}{10}$.  But $\big|-\frac{9}{10}\big| < 1$, so it converges.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track, you can write the series as:

$$\sum_{n=4}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{9}{10}= \sum_{n=4}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n$$ with $a_n=(\frac{9}{10})^n$

Then you are able to use the [Alternating Series Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) which basically says an alternating series in convergent if the absolute value of the coefficients are decreasing. which is the case here. Since $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0 $